# Comparison of two files using awk and print non matched records

Tags: linux, awk

I am comparing two files file1 and file2, i need to print the updated records of file2 which am comparing in file1. i need data changes of file2 and newly added records

File1:

```
1|footbal|play1
2|cricket|play2
3|tennis|play3
5|golf|play5
```

File2:

```
1|footbal|play1
2|cricket|play2
3|tennis|play3
4|soccer|play4
5|golf|play6
```

output file:

```
4|soccer|play4
5|golf|play6
```

i have tried the below solution but its not the expected output

```
awk -F'|' 'FNR == NR { a[$3] = $3; a[$1]=$1; next; } { if ( !($3 in a) && !($1 in a) ) { print $0; } }' file1.txt file2.txt
```

i have compared the column1 and column3 from both files

Comment: Are the records sorted? If they are you can use `comm` to get your difference.

Comment: actual ids are random numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"}FNR==NR{a[$1,$3];next} !(($1,$3) in a)' Input_file1  Input_file2
```

OR a non-one liner form of solution.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="|"
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$1,$3]
  next
}
!(($1,$3) in a)
'  Input_file1  Input_file2
```

Explanation: Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '               ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{              ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS="|"            ##Setting FS as pipe here as per Input_file(s).
}                   ##Closing BEGIN block for this awk code here.
FNR==NR{            ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when 1st Input_file named file1 is being read.
  a[$1,$3]          ##Creating an array named a with index os $1,$3 of current line.
  next              ##next will skip all further statements.
}
!(($1,$3) in a)     ##Checking condition if $1,$3 are NOT present in array a then print that line from Input_file2.
'  Input_file1  Input_file2     ##mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Output will be as follows.

```
4|soccer|play4
5|golf|play6
```

Comment: one last question here we are doing column by column comparison right not reading the complete row? just for clarification because i need to compare 10 columns in file1 and 10 columns in file2 with 4 million records. if read row by row its a performance issue.

Comment: @rakeshkandukuri, yes it is doing column by column it has `$1,$3` so yes you could put field numbers there. Also if you want to compare whole line then use $0 itself. Please go through my explanation once and lemme know  if any queries.

Comment: i am using command NR==FNR {exclude[$0];next} !($0 in exclude)' file1 file2 for file full comparison and 'BEGIN{FS="|"}FNR==NR{a[$1,$3];next} !(($1,$3) in a)' Input_file1  Input_file2 using this for column comparison of two files. question is if i add more columns in the second command does it impact performance? currently i am comparing 30 columns of two files it is taking more time than first command. any idea?

Comment: @rakeshkandukuri, you mean you will check 30 columns present in another file or not? Hoonn we need to check it but then we have no other option apart from this, until/unless you want to compare whole line itself which will be easier for awk as well as for us to maintain.

Comment: Yes i am comparing 30 columns in file1 to 30 columns in file2. i think its a performance issue. if i use $0 does it compare row by row?

Comment: @rakeshkandukuri, If you have 30 columns(Total in line) then you can do $0 rather than mentioning fields 1 by 1, lemme know on same.

Comment: actually i am comparing same file it has two versions old version and new version. file has 35 columns, i need to compare 30 columns because other 5 columns has too many updates. so comparing more columns will be a performance impact. any better solution please let me know.